# EXTLINUX warns to install grub

Tags: debian, grub, boot-loader

While doing `apt-get dist-upgrade` on a `Debian GNU/Linux Jessie` EXTLINUX warned me that now was mandatory to install `grub`.

[image]

The system was installed after an image not done by me: is it safe to ignore the warning? Have I to install `grub` also if now it's not installed and everything works (until I reboot, maybe)?

Can you please give me pointers?

Comment: @lazyfrosch Well, something has to be explained better: doing verbatim what suggested resulted in a not-bootable box. Maybe the wrong part (my fault) was `grub-install` on the MBR (partition was ext3). I restarted and executing `apt-get` and nothing more and it was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system won't boot anymore, since EXTLINUX config won't be updated.

Install grub and tell him where to install its boot loader.

`apt-get install grub-pc`

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this while upgrading Debian Wheezy to Debian Jessie on a VPS. The solution was to keep the old version of extlinux. Source: http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/install/extlinux-on-jessie.html

Hold the old extlinux:

```
echo "extlinux hold" | dpkg --set-selections
```

Then upgrade:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
```

Reboot should still work.

If you do a kernel update, as far as I understand, you should update the extlinux config manually. See this question: [Kernel upgrade with EXTLINUX on Debian](https://serverfault.com/questions/755745/kernel-upgrade-with-extlinux-on-debian)

Comment: IMO installing grub is a lot less work in the long run, since you don't have any manual actions anymore after future kernel updates.

Comment: You are right, but installing Grub is not always an option. On my VPS, replacing `extlinux` with `grub` or `grub2` results in a non-booting system.