# Kernel upgrade with EXTLINUX on Debian

Tags: debian, boot-loader

I would like to upgrade the Debian stock kernel to a compiled kernel packed as a .deb package.

Running the:

```
dpkg -i linux-image-x.x.Custom_amd64.deb
```

triggers the grub-update and, as I see from filesystem, the creation of the initrd file.

But now, how I tell EXTLINUX to boot from the new kernel?

Comment: Do you see the new kernel in Grub when you reboot ?

Comment: Well, no, grub is skipped outright by extlinux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing different introduced by Debian: install extlinux as usual with:

```
extlinux --install /boot/extlinux
```

make sure kernel image is present with matching initrd;

create a /boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf file like:

```
default linux
timeout 1
label linux
linux ../vmlinuz-4.4.0
append initrd=../initrd.img-4.4.0 root=/dev/vda1 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 ro quiet

label linux-stock
kernel ../vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64
append initrd=../initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/vda1 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 ro quiet
```

note the path are right in a box in which /boot is not a partition on its own (it is part of / partition).

If the kernel image is too large, use the keyword linux (not kernel).